# grpc Protofile service contract

Tags: grpc, proto

I want to build a like-service with a grpc api.
I saw couple of examples and they all only had one service contract (apparently for in and out).
When I build it like this, can I send GET and POST to this service, or do I need two contracts for it?

```
service LikeService{
    rpc LikePicture(PictureId) returns (Likes) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP verbs|methods (`GET`, `POST` etc.) aren't accessible to gRPC developers (and everything's a `POST`).

If you're anticipating `POST` as a way to submit likes and `GET` as a way to retrieve likes, you may want to consider something of the form:

```proto
service LikeService{
    rpc AddLike(PictureId) returns () {}
    rpc GetLikes(PictureId) returns (Likes) {}
}
```

> **NOTE** The `AddLike` method need not return anything if a successful call provides sufficient information.